# IBus, i3 and different keyboard layouts

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, i3-window-manager

I've been using i3 with IBus for quite some time. Since I failed to discover a sensible way to use i3 with different keyboard layouts, I just edited `~/.config/i3/config`, setting everything to key codes, `mod` key set to *Alt*.

It works perfectly for the English and Russian keyboard layouts, but not so well for the Spanish one. Kinda frayed around the edges.

```
...
# modifier = Alt, $sup = Wind0ws key
set $mod Mod1
##set $sup Mod4
...
```

This one is the most annoying case. It beats me how this particular definition can be keyboard layout dependent, but it won't work with the Spanish layout:

```
...
# kill focused window [q]
bindcode $mod+Shift+24 kill
...
```

The full `~/.config/i3/config` is [here](https://github.com/Tyrn/dotfiles/blob/main/dot_config/i3/config)

I am not really sure that my general approach is the correct one.

Comment: I set up my layouts with `setxkbmap`, and one bindsym (defined with English letter) works in both layouts. This is default i3 behavior ("sensible way") noted in the docs: "By default, keybindings are translated in Group1 ***and are active in all groups***." So, I suppose you have weird layout problem (for example, caused by deprecated xmodmap), and `xev` is your best friend.